# What to change in /etc/sudoers to allow restarting service?

Tags: tomcat, sudo

I want an unprivileged user to be able to restart tomcat on my server. So I edited /etc/sudoers as follows

```
username  ALL=/etc/init.d/tomcat6
```

However, when the user runs /etc/init.d/tomcat6 restart he gets this error:

```
Starting tomcat server...
 touch: cannot touch `/var/tomcat6/logs/catalina.out': Permission denied
/var/tomcat6/bin/catalina.sh: line 314: /var/tomcat6/logs/catalina.out: Permission denied
```

How do I allow this user to run tomcat without giving him write permission on the log file /var/tomcat6/logs/catalina.out ?

```
[root@jsp1 ~]# ll /var/tomcat6/logs/catalina.out
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 272669097 Feb 27 21:50 /var/tomcat6/logs/catalina.out
```

Comment: This may be redundant, but you were unclear in your question--are you running the service command with sudo?  I.e., `sudo /etc/init.d/tomcat6`?

Comment: no, I wasn't running the command using sudo. Sorry my bad... It works just fine now with sudo. So thanks a lot Redmumba :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Make sure to actually run the command with sudo when you try it.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to use the `service` command for this, so I came up with this:

```
%tomcat7 ALL=NOPASSWD:/usr/sbin/service tomcat7*
```

This allows everyone in tomcat7-group to start/stop/restart the tomcat service with `sudo service tomcat7 <command>` without typing their password.